# SSIS import file versus retrieving data directly from source

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We wish to import data into a SQL Server database from a source location located elsewhere in the company WAN in another country.

We are to be using SSIS to perform the import but wonder where would be the best place to perform the extract and transform. We could create a view on the source SQL server and SSIS will directly retrieve data from that. The alternative would be to drop a file out of the source and have SSIS import the data from that file.

I am thinking the former is a cleaner solution but would be interested to know whether there are any benefits in using files or potential issues with grabbing the data direct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using files if possible, especially if your starting point is a database.  By extracting to a file, you would be adding an unnecessary layer in the process that would increase the possiblity of errors.  Typical issues of using extracted files include unwittingly using an old / incomplete file (if extract failed) and masking user manually edited changes (direct in file for data issues).

If you have a SQL Server database, then creating a stored procedure, view or entering sql into SSIS would give you defined interface between source and SSIS.  Including the transform with the extract does blur the interface a little, but is quite common for simple transformation that do not depend on any target (or secondary source) data for the load.

An issue you may need to consider when grabbing data (with either approach) is the transactional state of data.  Depending on your source, you may need to handle data in various states of completeness and act appropriately.